# Remove extra space on top of UISearchController in UINavBar

Tags: swift, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I added a UISearchController in the navigation bar. But it has this extra top padding which I don't want. I used UIsearchController instead of a `UITextField` because I need its `searchResultsController`. Is there a way to remove the extra space, or a way to copy the `searchResultsController` behavior with `UITextField`. I created the view programmatically btw.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    setupSearchBar()
}

func setupSearchBar(){
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: ResultController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .yellow
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' to false
Setting the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets value to false

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't change anything